# Can we create mac app on older xcodes (8.x ,6.x) and older MAcosx (10.11) and notarise them

Tags: notarize

We have our build systems in older macosx (10.11) and xcode 8 & 6 .Recently apple has introduced notarisation of apps for catalina (10.15). can i create an app in older macosx (10.11) and try to notarise that in another mac machine which will have xcode 10 and macosx 10.14 .Please let us know its possible or not .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, notarization can be performed on any machine with xcode 10 or higher.